# irreducibility for almost every polynomial in a certain class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to find $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $V(f-\alpha) \cap V(g-\beta)= \text{(a point)}$ iff  $(\alpha,\beta) \neq (0,0)$.

This is motivated by a homework problem, but in its current form it is quite far removed from the homework problem (find a finite type extension $A$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that the spectrum of $A/(x-\alpha,y-\beta)$ is irreducible iff $(\alpha,\beta) \neq (0,0)$).

I am having trouble with this: it would have been much easier for me to come up with an example where the variety is reducible except at a finite set.  Do you have any ideas?

---

Edit:   Just brainstorming below here:  I have been thinking about a more helpful reduction of the problem:

Let $f_1,...f_k \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z_1,...z_k]$, and let $\mathbb{C}[z_1,...z_n]/\langle f_1(0,0,z_1,...z_n), f_2(0,0,z_1,...z_n),...,f_k(0,0,z_1,...z_n) \rangle$ be a finite ring extension of $\mathbb{C}$.  Then for all $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}[z_1,...z_n]/\langle f_1(a,b,z_1,...z_n), f_2(a,b,z_1,...z_n),...,f_k(a,b,z_1,...z_n) \rangle$ is a finite ring extension of $\mathbb{C}$.

My homework problem is equivalent to the existence of  $f_1...f_k$ so that $\mathbb{C}[z_1,...z_n]/\langle f_1(a,b,z_1,...z_n), f_2(a,b,z_1,...z_n),...,f_k(a,b,z_1,...z_n) \rangle$ has an irreducible spectrum for $(a,b) \neq 0$ and a reducible spectrum for $(a,b)=0$.

This would imply that  $\mathbb{C}[z_1,...z_n]/\langle f_1(0,b,z_1,...z_n), f_2(0,b,z_1,...z_n),...,f_k(0,b,z_1,...z_n) \rangle$ has an irreducible spectrum for $b \neq 0$ and a reducible spectrum for $b=0$.  Thus if there is an example that homework is asking for, then there is also an example of a finite type extension $A'$ of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $A/\langle x-a \rangle$ is irreducible iff $a \neq 0$.

I am now going to try to find an example of this or show it doesn't exist.

Comment: I doubt this can happen.

Comment: @Mohan Taking $\alpha=\beta\ne 0$ doesn't this imply that $(f,g)$ is maximal, so that $f=x-\alpha_0$ and $g=y-\beta_0$ for some $\alpha_0,\beta_0$? In this case one take $\alpha=\alpha_0$ and $\beta=\beta_0$ to see this is impossible.

Comment: a point in affine space.  I am a bit stuck because it seems that this is the only type of example that I would get from a finite ring extension $A/\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.  Btw, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @DeJong Did you see my comment above? Maybe I'm being silly, but I think this is impossible. PS, I hope you're related to the famous De Jong. :P